# MongoDB: only return documents if it hasn't existed previously in a different condition

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregate

There is a collection called `orders`. I want to return all failed orders, but only if there hasn't been a previous order with the same `order_ref` and `transaction_ref` that has `order_status : "completed"`. I cant do anything with the customer_id as the order ref/transaction_ref may appear  multiple times under different customers.

See below documents in the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed5070ccff6bd711a61f09d"),
    "customer_id" : ObjectId("5c9b3779f01ee12cc039038b"),
    "order_info" : {
        "refs" : {
            "order_ref" : "AAA123",
            "transaction_ref" : "123456"
        }
    },
    "order_date" : ISODate("2020-05-01T13:00:10.824Z"),
    "order_status" : "completed"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed51720cff6bd711a635514"),
    "customer_id" : ObjectId("5ed50fe0cff6bd711a62aae7"),
    "order_info" : {
        "refs" : {
            "order_ref" : "AAA123",
            "transaction_ref" : "123456"
        }
    },
    "order_date" : ISODate("2020-06-01T13:00:10.824Z"),
    "order_status" : "failed"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed51725cff6bd711a635978"),
    "customer_id" : ObjectId("5ed50809cff6bd711a6204f7"),
    "order_info" : {
        "refs" : {
            "order_ref" : "XXX123",
            "transaction_ref" : "654321"
        }
    },
    "order_date" : ISODate("2020-06-01T13:00:10.824Z"),
    "order_status" : "failed"
}
```

In the above examples, I would expect only `_id : 5ed51725cff6bd711a635978` to be returned as the other order_ref failed record had a completed record before. I assume I can do this with some of the aggregate/map functions but I'm quite new to mongoDB so any advice  would be appreciated.